# Facebook javascript sdk how get friends with new version api

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I am trying to get users's friends with new method /me/taggable_friends (i use permission user_friends)

```
FB.api('/me/taggable_friends', function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

but response is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the new developer app review process - which was recently introduced.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: How can I test my app before submit the review.I have same problem when get the user's friends.